# Stored procedure Update Statement missing column dynamic creation

Tags: sql-server

Here is my scenario. I am having Stored procedure with 5 parameters for particular table. But table schema is having only 3 columns. Is there any way to create 2 missing columns dynamically while Stored Procedure is running?. How can we handle the missing column exception. Please help me.

Thanks,
Sakthi

Comment: Why 5 parameters if there are only three columns? What is the need to add two columns while the procedure runs if no one is going to see them after it is done? Show us some code.

Comment: Here's one way to do add a column inside a stored procedure. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic502806-338-1.aspx but it is **REALLY** not recommended. Whatever your'e trying to do... it's wrong.

Comment: An example would really help this question. Without it, we're simply guessing what you are actually trying to do. Please add a simplified example of your issue.